# WordPress custom post type create data in a data.json?

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress

I'm creating a custom WordPress portfolio plugin, and I've created a custom post type with several different custom metaboxes. They ask for things like project data, type of project, etc.

That part of the plugin all works perfectly fine, but the script I'm using requires the data to be in a data.json, and then it automatically generates the HTML from the data.json.  Is it possible to append a data.json file using a WordPress custom post type? I would not want the post to create a page, which I can do, only append information in the data.json.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the script you're using open source? So we can view the docs

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/NUKnightLab/TimelineJS

Answer (score 0):

Can the script use ajax to retrieve the data in json format? If so, you can create an ajax callback using [wp_ajax](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_(action)) to retrieve the metadata.

In your js file/script.

```
var json;

jQuery.post(
    ajaxurl, 
    {
        'action': 'get_portfolio',
        'post_id': <POST_ID>
    }, 
    function(response){
        json = response;
    } );
```

On your plugin:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_portfolio', 'get_portfolio' );

function get_portfolio() {
    $metadata = get_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'] ); // do some sanitation as well
    echo json_encode($metadata);
}
```

Comment: The script locates a div with an ID of `timeline` then outputs the JSON data in that div, so I don't think the AJAX route would work.  It's a pre-built jQuery script, so modifying it isn't an option either.  I'm pretty much left with just creating a JSON based on custom post type information - if that's even possible.